# How do I get full permission to my files?

Tags: permissions, files

I have run into this problem too many times. Sometimes when I'm trying to run a command on the terminal it will say "Permission Denied." How can I get that permission??

Comment: @AvinashRaj `chmod 777` serves debugging purposes, no more. Don't end up with a full-777 system.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified *which* commands caused this error, because the cause (and most appropriate solution) will be quite different depending on what it was that caused this error.  The best solution is probably *not* to change file permissions.

Comment: To echo what @JohnWHSmith said, **DO NOT** set all files to `chmod 777`.  This will only end up with a hopelessly insecure system and (if it was done system-wide) there is no way to un-do it except to wipe and reinstall.  I repeat, the appropriate solution is most likely *not* to change file permissions.

Comment: `chmod +x <filename>` will give execution permission to file. And use `sudo <command>` to run as root user

Answer (score 1):

@Avinash Raj 
is useful but , 
I think what user meant 
without realizing it
is how to run a script ./script
you need to change the mode and
get the permission you can 
achieve that with

```
chmod +x script_name.extension
```

which makes the script executable and let you run it !

**or** you can **right click the file** go to **properties** and then
**permissions** and check the **executable checkbox**

and then back to terminal to actually run it .

after **if you double click** it you get options to **open in text editor or run in terminal** etc..

Comment: In addition to this, you can't add executable mode (+x) to a file inside a non-linux (ext) filesystem since they don't support that functionality (like in windows NTFS or FAT32). So ensure that the file you are trying to execute is in the Linux filesystem/directory.

Answer (score 0):

The *permission denied* error (code 13) warns you that your request cannot be carried out by the system, since your user/group IDs do not give you the required privileges. For instance, consider this file in my home directory :

```
$ ls -l test.txt
-rw-r----- 1 me mygroup 0 Jul  1 03:54 test.txt
```

The `rw-r-----` part states that the owner (`me`) can perform read/write operations on the file, while members of the `mygroup` group can read it. Others can't do anything.

In order to read this file, you'll type :

```
$ cat test.txt
```

Yet, if you're not `me`, and don't belong to the `mygroup` group, you'll get a beautiful `Permission denied (13)` error.

If you want to know more about the UNIX permissions system, have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions), [here](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Permissions.html) or [here](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml). Note that this system applies to all programs (commands) on your system. Any program trying to read `test.txt` must be running as `me`, or someone in the `mygroup` group in order to succeed (otherwise, the same error will occur).

When performing administration tasks such as package management or system configuration, it is usually necessary to have `root` privileges. These tasks require access to files owned by `root`, or the execution of *kernel-tasks* that can only be carried out with super-user privileges. On Ubuntu, you can run a command as `root` using `sudo` :

```
$ sudo mycommand
```

However, this requires you to be registered as a *sudoer*, which will probably be the case if you're the first or only user on that machine. [More about sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).